# Replacing characters in a string between delimiter - Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I can't seem to figure this one out. I know that a regular expression can be used, but haven't really had any experience with creating them. I have a string of dates that looks like this:

```
( (Mon 3:23PM EDT) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Wed, Sep 2) ( (Tue, Sep 1) ( (Mon, Aug 31) ( (Fri, Aug 28) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Fri, Aug 21) ( (Mon, Aug 17) ( (Thu, Aug 13) ( (Thu, Aug 13)
```

When there is a time stamp in the string, such as the 3:23 above, I need to replace that with the today's date. I am getting today's date in the format I need by using the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat necessaryFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, MMM dd");
String todaysDate = necessaryFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Essentially the string should be

```
 ( (Mon, Sep 7) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Wed, Sep 2) ( (Tue, Sep 1) ( (Mon, Aug 31) ( (Fri, Aug 28) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Fri, Aug 21) ( (Mon, Aug 17) ( (Thu, Aug 13) ( (Thu, Aug 13)
```

So far I have tried to use something along the lines of this, but all it is doing is removing the first piece of the string between the parenthesis:

```
String origStr = links.text().substring(0, links.text().indexOf("("))+
            links.text().substring(links.text().indexOf(")")+"))".length());
```

Comment: something like replaceAll("\d+:\d+[AP]M", yourDate);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `replaceAll` with the following regex:

```
(?i)\\([a-z]{3} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}[pa]m [a-z]{3}\\)
```

Regex breakdown:

- `(?i)` - Make the pattern case-insensitive
- `\\(` - a literal opening round bracket
- `[a-z]{3}` - 3 letters
- `\\d{1,2}:` - a space, 1 or 2 digits, and a `:`
- `\\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `[pa]m` - `PM` or `AM`
- `[a-z]{3}` a space with 3 letters
- `\\)` - a closing round bracket.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/60uqEx):

```
String str = "( (Mon 3:23PM EDT) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Wed, Sep 2) ( (Tue, Sep 1) ( (Mon, Aug 31) ( (Fri, Aug 28) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Fri, Aug 21) ( (Mon, Aug 17) ( (Thu, Aug 13) ( (Thu, Aug 13)";
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)\\([a-z]{3} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}[pa]m [a-z]{3}\\)", "(" + todaysDate + ")");
System.out.println(str);
```

Today's output: `( (Mon, Sep 07) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Thu, Sep 3) ( (Wed, Sep 2) ( (Tue, Sep 1) ( (Mon, Aug 31) ( (Fri, Aug 28) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Wed, Aug 26) ( (Fri, Aug 21) ( (Mon, Aug 17) ( (Thu, Aug 13) ( (Thu, Aug 13)`